# Nothing is showing on webpage when i use a certain component in react app

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Card from './components/Card';
import Accrodion from './components/Accrodion';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="container">
    <Card />
    <Accrodion />
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Card.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Card() {
  return (
    <div className="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." className="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
  <div className="card-body">
    <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li className="list-group-item">An item</li>
    <li className="list-group-item">A second item</li>
    <li className="list-group-item">A third item</li>
  </ul>
  <div className="card-body">
    <a href="#" className="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" className="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
  )
}
```

Everything works fine when I comment Card component in app.js file, but when I try to use it, nothing is on the webpage. When I inspect the page the root div is empty.
I can't figure out what is the problem here. There is no error in any code file.

Comment: Not directly related, but *style="width: 18rem;"* - this is not how you use inline styles in JSX.

Comment: Are you sure there is no error in the console? It sure sounds like an error.

Comment: @BrianThompson I think that's actally the problem here

Comment: This is the error I am getting in console.Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.@BrianThompson

Comment: @BrianThompson thanks solved the problem.